# Montar boletim escolar

Tags: php, sql

Estou tentando montar um SQL para exibir os resultados de um Boletim Escolar. Na tabela de notas eu tenho os dados da seguinte maneira

Tabela Notas

```
MATERIA   | NOTA | BIMESTRE
PORTUGUES |  10  |   1
PORTUGUES |  8   |   2
PORTUGUES |  6   |   3
PORTUGUES |  5   |   4
```

Para exibir esses dados eu quero que fiquem da seguinte maneira

```
MATERIA   |   1Bim   |   2Bim  |   3Bim   |    4Bim
PORTUGUES |    10    |     8   |     6    |     5
```

Como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/551654-converter-linhas-em-colunas-pivot/     https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/08b8e6b1-6b06-44bb-a5cd-f730e88c7ed6/coluna-em-linha?forum=transactsqlpt   CASE , MAX e GROUP BY dá para resolver no SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select max(case when bimestre = 1 then nota else null end) 1bim,
       Max(case when bimestre = 2 then nota else null end) 2bim,
       ...
From notas
```

Poderia , ser for o caso , agrupar por aluno também.

Comment: Motta valeu amigo deu certo